# _Longlong was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I am going through tutorial 33 of the SDL 2 tutorials on lazyfoo.net (source code is available at http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/33_file_reading_and_writing/index.php at the bottom of the page), and I am getting the compiler error "_Longlong was not declared in this scope". I am using g++ version 5.3 in Codeblocks 16.01. What can I do to resolve this build error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is like error (not-portable coding) in the example, as reported in https://forums.libsdl.org/viewtopic.php?p=42648 by jungletek in 2015:

> I posted this in a newer thread about the same issue, it's sad that
>   people never follow up with their solutions on the internet...
>
> Quote: I believe this is a combination of a MinGW bug (update MinGL to
>   a newer version), and a bug/error(?) with Lazy Foo's code.
>
> Changing all instances of '_Longlong' to 'long long' causes the code
>   to compile properly, and the executable seems to perform as expected,
>   as far as I can see. If anyone can let me know if this is in some way
>   an incorrect solution, I'd love to hear it as I'm still very much in
>   the process of learning.
>
> Also make sure you're compiling for the c++11 standard, using the
>   proper compiler flags.

So, you can try to add line (before first usage of _Longlong) with typedef of `_Longlong` into `long long` (both are 64 bit ints on many platforms):

```
 typedef long long _Longlong;
```

And the `_Longlong` sounds too much like [something from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) desert of Redmond, WA, which is not the main target of gcc compiler.